# Not able to load devtools package in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, devtools

when I run the code library(devtools) the error I got is:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ in inDL(x,
as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):  unable to load shared
object
'C:/Users/c-yash.bhatt/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/processx/libs/x64/processx.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found. In
addition: Warning message: package ‘devtools’ was built under R
version 4.0.2
```

Comment: What version of R are you currently running?

Comment: Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: I found a similar problem with the installation of a different R package. The problem was due to the name of a folder in the path, which contained a "forbidden" character (maybe in your path the source of the problem is `c-yash.bhatt`). I suggest to remove `devtools` and reinstall it in a different directory (using the option `lib` of `install.packages`).

Comment: @MarcoSandri If the issue was with the path, it would stand to reason this would happen for any package. Also, I feel like installing packages in a different directory than what R creates is a potentially dangerous notion.

Comment: @Phil This is just a try, of course. The aim is to check if my suggestion is correct. In my past experience, I found one package with this problem and I solved it changing the name of the "problematic" folder.